# Add description text and links in zoomable circle packing graph with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I am still new at d3 and want to create a zoomable circle graph with title text, description text and links (the links only displayed in the leafs) that can be clicked and open a new page.

I have figured out how I can add those in a normal circle pack, but I can't implement it with the zoomable circle graph (not displayed)

It would be so great if someone could help me with it because I am so stuck with this.

Here my full working example at CodePen https://codepen.io/Lea12/pen/ExvoEgx

And the not working code

```js
var description = g.selectAll("text")
                   .append("text")
                   .attr("class","description")
                   .attr("dy", +80)
                   .style("display", function(d) { 
                     return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
                   })
                   .text(function(d) {
                     return d.data.description;
                   });
  
var url = g.selectAll("text")
           .append("text")
           .attr("class","description")
           .attr("dy", +120)
           .text("click for more information")
           .on("click", function(d) {
             window.open(d.data.url,"_blank")
           })
```

Comment: A `<text>` element cannot be a child of another `<text>`(https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermTextContentChildElement). Just do `append("tspan")`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I have updated the code with tspan and the text is displayed. But with tspan it is now displayed in one row. Would it be possible to display the 3 elements (headline/description/url)one below the other? I have also found out how the url is only displayed at the leafs, but due to the zooming it is not possible to click the links. Would it be possible to stop the zooming out for the leaf nodes when clicking on the link? I updated the code in my CodePen. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I see you are new here at Stack Overflow. Since you now have a **different** problem, the best idea is writing a new question, describing your new problem in details.